# Python Beautiful Soup and Dealing with a Non-Existent Table (for Dynamic Webpages)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the following commands to successfully scrape data from a table on multiple webpages through an iteration function:

```
 Sales = soup.find('table', id="tblSales")
 SaleData = Sales.find_all('tr')
    for tr in SaleData:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        SaleData = [i.text for i in td]
        print(SaleData)
```

The issue is that sometimes the table doesn't exist on the page (there are no "sales" so there is no table inserted into the page). So python throws an error and stops. When the table doesn't exist, the webpage has the following html:

```
<div>
<span id="ucSaleInfo_lblNoSales">
    <p style="text-align:center"><em>No Sales Information Available</em></p>
</span>                                            
</div>
```

Is there a way to deal with non-existent tables in the soup?

Comment: Just use an `if statement` and check for `None`, which means there's no table.

Comment: I'm a novice. I'll look up how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just check if `Sales` exists

```
if Sales := soup.find('table', id="tblSales"):
    SaleData = Sales.find_all('tr')
        for tr in SaleData:
            td = tr.find_all('td')
            SaleData = [i.text for i in td]
            print(SaleData)
```

OR (essentially same thing)

```
Sales = soup.find('table', id="tblSales")
if Sales:
    SaleData = Sales.find_all('tr')
        for tr in SaleData:
            td = tr.find_all('td')
            SaleData = [i.text for i in td]
            print(SaleData)
```

Comment: Thank you, this logic makes sense. But the table parser code is throwing an error still because it can't find the <tr> tag I believe in the string. (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all')

Comment: Here is the full error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 89, in <module>
    SaleData = Sales.find_all('tr')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: I changed the method entirely because it became too convoluted to keep going with my original fix.

Comment: Thank you! Still learning.